# Show element when hover absolute position overlay but keep all events

Tags: html, css

Sometimes I have a bunch of elements to which I would like to add some info box when I hover over them. I've tried to add absolute positioned overlay to capture hover events and it works but I lose all events for elements behind overlay. To solve this I've tried `pointer-events: none;` but now the tooltip is not being displayed on hover.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width : fit-content; /* Edit0, parent could be smaller than hover-box */
}

.hover-box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* click will work, but not hover */
  /* pointer-events: none;  */
}

.info {
  display: none;
}

.hover-box:hover+.info {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>btn0</button>
  <button>btn1</button>
  <div class="hover-box"></div>
  <button class="info">info</button>
</div>
```

Edit0 :
Added fit-content to show the problem better. Parent could be smaller.

Edit1 : Maybe there is some way to have events on hover-box and buttons at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set the z-index of the buttons to `2`, which places them above the overlay and allows them to be clicked.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.hover-box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.info {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.parent:hover .info {
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  margin: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="hover-box"></div>
  <button>btn0</button>
  <button>btn1</button>
  <button class="info">info</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but hover-box have no meaning. Parent could be actually smaller than hover-box. Will add edit.

Comment: z-index is an option in simple example, however imagine something more complex.

Comment: @lisichkaggg z-index is used on projects of all size to define a stacking context for elements. Managing z-index on larger projects can be done effectively when using the [right strategy](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/02/css-z-index-large-projects/). The size of your project is not a reason to circumvent z-index. If you really want to do this without z-index you can handle the hover events using JS instead, but you should design your system to meet your *current* needs, and adjust it to fit your needs as they change. You don't build a system to support a million users when you have 10.

Comment: You should maintain your z-index in a central location and document the context of each z-index. See [maintainable z-index](https://medium.com/@houhoucoop/building-a-maintainable-z-index-system-for-large-projects-dce028452a5a) for a great explanation.